# How to make only one element activate vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How to make only one element activate vue js?
I have 3 drop-down lists, 3 are activated at once, how do I make sure that only one is activated?

As far as I understand, this needs to be done through a loop, but this framework is not given to me

```
<tr class="inputs-table">
            <td>Type object: </td>
            <td>
                <div class="select">
                    <div class="select-header form-control" v-on:click="AddForm">
                        <span class="select__current">Please select one option</span>
                        <span class="select__off">х</span>
                    </div>
                    <addForm v-if="addedForm" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="inputs-table">
            <td>Type business-model: </td>
            <td>
                <div class="select">
                    <div class="select-header form-control" v-on:click="AddForm">
                        <span class="select__current">Please select one option</span>
                        <span class="select__off">х</span>
                    </div>
                    <addForm v-if="addedForm"/>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>




import addForm from './modal/addForm.vue';

export default {
    name: 'Index',
    data() {
        return {
            addedForm: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        AddForm(){
            this.addedForm = true;
        },
        closeForm() {
            this.$parent.addedForm = false;
        }
    },
    components: {
        addForm,
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your dropdown list?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/upk2oe 
here he is

Comment: It seems you are not using a component library so there is some difficulty to identify what are the components you are mentioning, such as where is a dropdown. Could you please update your question with some Screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your question and the given screenshot on the comment section, it seems you implement dropdown list in your `addForm` component and when you click on `<div class="select-header form-control" v-on:click="AddForm">` in "type object" or "Type business-model" component will expand the `addForm` component and your problem is when you click on one header both `addForm` components are visible.

In that case, there may be several methods to fix this. One easy way to add numbering to each component and only activate the `addForm` if number equals.

```
<tr class="inputs-table">
            <td>Type object: </td>
            <td>
                <div class="select">
                    <div class="select-header form-control" v-on:click="AddForm(1)">
                        <span class="select__current">Please select one option</span>
                        <span class="select__off">х</span>
                    </div>
                    <addForm v-if="addedForm === 1" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="inputs-table">
            <td>Type business-model: </td>
            <td>
                <div class="select">
                    <div class="select-header form-control" v-on:click="AddForm(2)">
                        <span class="select__current">Please select one option</span>
                        <span class="select__off">х</span>
                    </div>
                    <addForm v-if="addedForm === 2"/>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>




import addForm from './modal/addForm.vue';

export default {
    name: 'Index',
    data() {
        return {
            addedForm: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        AddForm(number){
            this.addedForm = number;
        },
        closeForm() {
            this.$parent.addedForm = false;
        }
    },
    components: {
        addForm,
    }
}
```

Since you are using 3 form element this would be enough but if you are planning to use a dynamic  number of components it would be great if you use for a method such as create list for each type object

```
items: [{id:1, title: 'Type Object'}, {id:2, title: 'Business Model'}]
```

Then use `v-for` in your `tr` component such as,

```
<tr class="inputs-table" v-for="item in items" key="item.id">
            <td>{{item.title}}: </td>
            <td>
                <div class="select">
                    <div class="select-header form-control" v-on:click="AddForm(item.id)">
                        <span class="select__current">Please select one option</span>
                        <span class="select__off">х</span>
                    </div>
                    <addForm v-if="addedForm === item.id"/>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```